# A good REHASH function for strings using hash table?

Tags: c++, string, hash

Most of the hashing functions i found on the internet are always using integers as one of their parameters along with the hash table size and the simplest rehash function i have encountered was this:

```
int rehash(int item, int tableSize) {
    return hash(item+1,tableSize);
}
```

and the hash function to usually go with this is:

```
int hash(int item, int tableSize) {
    return item % tableSize;
}
```

i was wondering if their is a string equivalent of this?

My hash function:

```
int hash(string& item, int n) {
    int hashVal = 0;
    int len = item.length();

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    hashVal = hashVal*37 + item[i];

    hashVal %= n;   

    if(hashVal < 0) hashVal += n;

    return hashVal;
}
```

Comment: Whats wrong with [`std::hash<std::string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) ?

Comment: is there a way to "increment" a string?

Comment: that makes no sense, strings are not numbers

Comment: that's why i'm asking if there is a equivalent rehash function to strings to the rehash function i just mentioned above